# Error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'offset'" when analysing GPX data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, gpx

I am following this tutorial while learing Python (https://towardsdatascience.com/how-tracking-apps-analyse-your-gps-data-a-hands-on-tutorial-in-python-756d4db6715d).

I am at the step where I want to plot 'time' and 'elevation'. But when I do this with:

```
plt.plot(df['time'], df['ele'])
plt.show()
```

I get the error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'offset'". If I plot 'longitude' and 'latitude' everything works fine.
I cannot find a way to solve this problem by myself.
This is "my" code so far:

```
import gpxpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
from geopy import distance

from math import sqrt, floor
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import haversine
#Import Plugins

gpx_file = open('01_Karlsruhe_Schluchsee.gpx', 'r')
gpx = gpxpy.parse(gpx_file)

data = gpx.tracks[0].segments[0].points

## Start Position
start = data[0]
## End Position
finish = data[-1]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['lon', 'lat', 'ele', 'time'])

for point in data:
    df = df.append({'lon': point.longitude, 'lat' : point.latitude,
                   'ele' : point.elevation, 'time' : point.time}, ignore_index=True)

print(df)
plt.plot(df['time'], df['ele'])
plt.show()
```

[Picture of my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBjiu.jpg)

Comment: What does your dataframe look like?

Comment: Please provide the full traceback such that we could help you

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). According to the tutorial you linked in your question your data frame has no column called `'ele'`. So please provide all information necessary to make an adequate answer possible.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. We need the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. I would recommend reading the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 7):

Removing the timezone from your 'time' column might do the trick. You can do this with `tz_localize`. Note that you have to call method `dt` to access column datetime properties:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.tz_localize(None)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the times in gpxpy have a time zone of SimpleTZ('Z'), which I think is their own implementation of the tzinfo abstract base class. That makes it "aware" as opposed to "naive" but apparently doesn't allow getting the offset.

See https://github.com/tkrajina/gpxpy/issues/209.

I fixed it as follows and also got the time zone for the first location in a track. (The track may have been done is a different time zone than local.)

```
import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
from timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder

def get_data(gpx):
    '''Currently Only does the first track and first segment'''
    tzf = TimezoneFinder()
    # Use lists for the data not a DataFrame
    lat = []
    lon = []
    ele = []
    time = []
    n_trk = len(gpx.tracks)
    for trk in range(n_trk):
        n_seg = len(gpx.tracks[trk].segments)
        first = True  # Flag to get the timezone for this track
        for seg in range(n_seg):
            points = gpx.tracks[trk].segments[seg].points
            for point in points:
                if(first):
                    # Get the time zone from the first point in first segment
                    tz_name = tzf.timezone_at(lng=point.longitude, lat=point.latitude)
                    first = False
                lat.append(point.latitude)
                lon.append(point.longitude)
                ele.append(point.elevation)
                try:
                    new_time = point.time.astimezone(ZoneInfo(tz_name))
                except:
                    new_time = point.time.astimezone(ZoneInfo('UTC'))
                time.append(new_time)
    return lat, lon, ele, time
```

With these changes the plots in PyPlot work as expected.

ZoneInfo is only available as of Python 3.9, and on Windows you also have to install tzdata (pip install tzdata) for ZoneInfo to work. For earlier versions you could do essentially the same thing using pytz.